# Formulario de contacto, no me llega el correo

Tags: php, html, ajax

Mi problema es que tengo un formulario hecho con HTML, PHP y AJAX que subí a mi pagina hace todo como "debería" pero a mi correo no llega el mensaje, les dejo mi código para que lo revisen:

HTML:

```
<h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
      <div id="note"></div>
      <div id="fields">
        <form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
          <div class="left">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombres Completos:" >
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Su Correo:" >
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de Tel&eacute;fono">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="">
              <div class="left">
                <input class="capthca" type="text" name="capthca" value="Capthca:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Capthca:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Capthca:' ) this.value=''">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="submit">submit</button>
              </div>
              <img src="captcha/captcha.php">
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="left pad_left2">
            <textarea name="content" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include 'contact_config.php';
 session_start();
 error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

 if($post)
 {
 include 'functions.php';

 $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
 $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
 $message = "Site visitor information:

 Name: ".$_POST['name']
 ."

 E-mail Address: ".$_POST['email']
 ."

 Phone: ".$_POST['phone']
 ."

 Message: ".$_POST['content'];


 $error = '';

 // Check name

 if(!$name)
 {
 $error .= 'Please enter your First name.<br />';
 }
 // Check email

 if(!$email)
 {
 $error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
 }

 if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
 {
 $error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
 }


 if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) &&       strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) != strtolower($_POST['capthca']))
 {
 $error .= "Incorect captcha.<br />";
 }
 if(!$error)
 {
 $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
 "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

 if($mail)
 {
 echo 'OK';
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
 }

 }
 ?>
```

JQUERY - AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax( { type: "POST", url: "contact.php", data: str, success:  function(msg){ 
            if(msg == 'OK') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message  and hide the form
                { result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br> <a href="#" onclick="freset();return false;">send another mail</a></div>'; $("#fields").hide(); }                           
            else
                { result = msg; } 
            $("#note").html(result); 
        } 
    }); 
    return false; 
}); 
});

function freset(){  
  $("#note").html('');
  document.getElementById('ajax-contact-form').reset();
  $("#fields").show();
 };
```

aparte hay otro doc .js

```
<?php
 // To
 define( 'ejemplo@gmail.com', 'ejemplo@gmail.com');
 ?>
```

Comment: un comentario, como regla general de seguridad: no es una buena idea enviar la version de php (o cualquier otra cosa) en la cabecera del email (al igual que en las cabeceras http), con esta información, un potencial atacante podría intentar explotar alguna vulnerabilidad conocida: existente o futura.

Comment: ahora mi problema es otro en localhost si envia el mensaje,pero al subirlo en el hosting no. Creen que me puede faltar algo?

Comment: Yo probaría a usar PHPMailer o alguno similar, para hacer el envio del mail, asi te ahorras los problemas que suele tener la función mail

Comment: La funcion mail() no funciona en local @Aniuska

Comment: hola @AlbertoMier yo configure el mercury en xampp para probar el envio de los correos, por eso los podia enviar desde el localhost. En realidad el problema era del servidor!. saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Te has  asegurado que tu proveedor hosting tiene habilitado el uso de la función mail? Contacta con ellos para asegurarte.

Si lo tienen habilitado, podrías mostrar los errores que produce para poder afinar un poco más la depuración.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola,se que ha pasado bastante tiempo,al final el si problema era del hosting...Muchas gracias por su ayuda! :D

Answer (score 0):

Intenta instalando una copia local de tu sitio utilizando WAMP o XAMP para descartar que sea un problema del servidor o de spam. Yo utilizo [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) para probar los correos enviados por medio de PHP de forma local (Esta herramienta es para Windows). Si todo funciona bien, podría ser un problema de envío por parte del servidor o recepción por parte del remitente.

Debes tener en cuenta también que el remitente (de donde se envía el correo) deberá contener el mismo dominio que el sitio. De otra forma hay una gran posibilidad de que se marque como spam.